# incompatible pointer to integer conversion initializing 'int' with an expression of type 'int (void)'

Tags: c, function, pointers, expression, cs50

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int get_cents(void);
int calculate_quarters(int cents);


int main(void)
{

    //Ask how many cents the customer is owed
    int cents = get_cents;

    // Calculate the number of quarters to give the customer
    int quarters = calculate_quarters(cents);
    cents = cents - quarters * 25;

}

int get_cents(void)
{
    int cents;
    do
    {
      cents = get_int("Changed owed: ");
    }

    while (cents < 0);
    return cents;
}

int calculate_quarters(int cents)
{
 return 0;
}
```

incompatible pointer to integer conversion initializing 'int' with an expression of type 'int (void)' [-Werror,-Wint-conversion]
int cents = get_cents;

Comment: You forgot adding `()` in `int cents = get_cents;`

Comment: (sighs in rookie mistakes :P) thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int cents = get_cents;
```

Here you are not really calling the function get_cents. You have to use parantheses like this:

```
int cents = get_cents(...);
```

The error is because `get_cents` is a pointer to that function and you are assigning the pointer to the int variable.